# Java8 lambda expression for sorting

Tags: java, java-8

In order to sort a collection can use following :

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collections;

public class LambdaSort {

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        ArrayList arr = new ArrayList();
        Collections.sort(arr);
    }
}
```

In this case the sort is redundant as the collection is empty.
In order to use a generic sort function instead of `Collections.sort` I create a new method which takes the sort function as parameter:

```
private void genericSort(() -> java.util.List)) {

}
```

But this does not type check and causes error :

```
Multiple markers at this line
    - Syntax error, insert "[ ]" to complete Dimension
    - Syntax error on token(s), misplaced construct(s)
    - Syntax error on token "void", @ expected after this token
    - Syntax error, insert "Identifier (" to complete 
     MethodHeaderName
    - Method breakpoint:LambdaSort [entry] - genericSort()
```

I intend to use the function as :

```
LambdaSort ls new LambdaSort()
ls.genericSort(Collections.sort(ls))
```

How should I define my `genericSort` in order to accept a generic sort function?

Comment: That looks like you are trying to invent new Java syntax, inspired by Haskell or so. Hint: do some research on Java lambdas and method references, and then check out the Consumer interface. There are just too many things wrong about your code.

Comment: `Collections.sort(list)` returns void. You can't pass it as a parameter

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Why do you need `genericSort` method at all?

If you need a custom sorting algorithm, you can use

```
java.util.Collections#sort(java.util.List<T>, java.util.Comparator<? super T>)
```

Looks like it is what you need. It accepts the list itself as a first argument and the sorting strategy as a second argument.

Regarding your code, the lamdba declaration **cannot be** a method parameter declaration. You can pass it as a argument when you call the method.

Moreover, the `() -> java.util.List)` is not a valid lambda declaration. It has extra parenthesis `)` and `java.util.List` it is not a valid `return` statement.

Comment: And just to add to this: The `Comparator` interface is now chock-full of default methods for generating instances for all kinds of sorting strategies: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Comparator.html

Answer (score 3):

To do something as you originally intended you can use:

```
private static void genericSort(Consumer<List<Integer>> f, List<Integer> l) {
    ...
    f.accept(l);
    ...
}
```

and call it so

```
genericSort(Collections::sort, new ArrayList<Integer>());
```

Comment: I was too lazy to write up exactly this content. But I appreciate you taking the time to write it :-)

Answer (score 1):

Ok, first off: in Java 8 something like

```
List<String> names = new ArrayList<>();
names.add("Jim");
names.add("Bob");

List<String> sortedNames = names.stream()
 .sorted(Comparators.natural())
 .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

can be used https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/package-summary.html

---

Apart from that, answering your generic question:

```
private void<T>(Comparator<T> comparator, List<T> list) {
 //do something
}
```

is possible